# Elasticsearch php-sdk

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I want query to return me 15 results.

```
 $params = array();
 $params['body']["size"] = 15; 
 $params['body']['query']['match']["country"] = 53;
 $results = $client->search($params);
```

and response:

```
Error 500 transfer closed with 33476 bytes remaining to read
```

I spent a lot of hours of debugging and I really need help.

Comment: are you sure that size is part of the body? Here it is not: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/_search_operations.html

Comment: I change it to 
"$params["size"] = 15".  

But again I got this error.

Comment: Are you currently able to do ANYTHING with elasticsearch? I.e. with default settings and almost no changes, like in the guide? If yes, then try to find what makes a difference. If no: do you have a personal firewall (look in the protocols), or are you in a country with certain internet "filtering", e.g. China, Turkey or the UK?

Comment: Yes I can do everything. I wrote my own method using cURL and is working fine. I send same query for both and still SDK is not working